# W10 after 1115 update did not work 2560x1440 resolution

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-10, resolution, intel-graphics

I have laptop MSI GE602OC with i7, Intel Graphic 4600 and GeForce 750M and monitor: DELL U2713HM. After 1115 update system does not support 2560x1440 resolution. I tried to install new drivers for integrated graphic card (It is responsible for the display via HDMI) but still nothing. Any ideas what can i do?

PS. Before update everything worked good.

Regards

Damian

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia drivers again?

Comment: No, give me 5 minutes :)

Comment: But first, look at this: [http://imgur.com/Ny67RmR](http://imgur.com/Ny67RmR)

Comment: Its entirely possible this problem is caused by Intel's driver not supporting the new build of Windows 10. Given the extremely lack of support for Windows 10 by Intel this is very likely.

Comment: NVIDIA driver update not improve the situation.